# Is startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges accurate enough for foursquare?

Tags: core-location

I'm working on a feature that uses the foursquare API to find venues nearby. Is `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` accurate enough for this? I.e., does foursquare use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` or do they use `startUpdatingLocation`, or both? If both, how should you use them together?

Even after reading this [data analisys of `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/), I'm still not sure which to use?

Also, what about for an app like Grindr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at that article I would say no but it depends entirely on what you mean by nearby. Remember that in a shopping centre it is extremely easy for their to be numerous venues near you in a 250 - 500 metre radius. I mean quite a few shops are 10 metres wide or so, same with coffee shops etc. But then again it depends what you mean by venue.

Personally if I was making the app though I'd want something more predictable and accurate than the significant location change method. That seems to be geared more towards finding out a persons locale rather than finding what they are near too within said locale. For proper location services I'd still want to use the fully fledged GPS data.